# Implementation of hierarchical bayesian model produces errors with PyMC

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

I'm trying to solve an exercise from [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158488410X) in which I'm supposed to fit data on temperature and elevation in Colorado to this model:

\begin{equation} \boldsymbol{Y} = \boldsymbol{\mu} + \boldsymbol{\alpha} \otimes \boldsymbol{1}_{n\times 1} + \boldsymbol{1}_{T\times 1} \otimes \boldsymbol{w} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
p(\boldsymbol{Y}| \boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{\alpha},\boldsymbol{w},\sigma^{2}_\epsilon) \sim N(\boldsymbol{\mu} + \boldsymbol{\alpha} \otimes \boldsymbol{1}_{n\times 1} + \boldsymbol{1}_{T\times 1} \otimes \boldsymbol{w}, \sigma^{2}_\epsilon I_{T n \times T n})
\end{equation}

$\boldsymbol{Y}$ is a vector $(Y_{1}, \dots , Y_{T})$ of observations (temperatures) at each time $t \in \{1,2,\dots, T\}$ where each $Y_{t} = (Y(s_{1}, t), \dots, Y(s_{n},t))$ describes a vector of observations in some location $s_{i}$ at time $t$. Therefore, we can join all observations for every single time and location in a $nT\times 1$ vector $\boldsymbol{Y}$:

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{Y} = \left(Y(s_{1}, t_{1}), Y(s_{2}, t_{1}), \dots, Y(s_{n}, t_{1}), \dots ,Y(s_{1}, t_{T}), Y(s_{2}, t_{T}), \dots Y(s_{n}, t_{T})\right)^{T}
\end{equation}

$\boldsymbol{\mu}$ is similar to $\boldsymbol{Y}$ and contains means that depend on a covariate in the form $\boldsymbol{\mu} = X(s_i, t)\boldsymbol{\beta}(t)$. On the contrary, $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ only depends on time $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = (\alpha(1),\dots, \alpha(T))$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ only depends on space $\boldsymbol{\omega} = (\omega(1),\dots, \omega(s_{n}))$. That is why we need to use kronecker products to obtain a $nT\times 1$ vector.

I wrote some code with PyMC to reproduce this [WinBUGS code](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~brad/data/ColoradoS-T1.bug) in which $\mu = \beta_{1} + \beta_{2}\text{Elevation}$. I think I obtained reasonable results. Now I want to extend this and use a $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ for each time $t$. This means the equation above should be:

\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}Y(s_{1}, t_{1}) \\ Y(s_{2}, t_{1}) \\ \vdots \\Y(s_{n}, t_{1}) \\ \vdots \\ Y(s_{1}, t_{T}) \\ Y(s_{2}, t_{T}) \\ \vdots \\Y(s_{n}, t_{T})\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}\beta_{0t_{1}} + \beta_{1t_{1}}\text{Elevation}(s_{1}) \\ \beta_{0t_{1}} + \beta_{1t_{1}}\text{Elevation}(s_{2}) \\ \vdots \\\beta_{0t_{1}} + \beta_{1t_{1}}\text{Elevation}(s_{n}) \\ \vdots \\ \beta_{0t_{T}} + \beta_{1t_{T}}\text{Elevation}(s_{1}) \\ \beta_{0t_{T}} + \beta_{1t_{T}}\text{Elevation}(s_{2}) \\ \vdots \\ \beta_{0t_{T}} + \beta_{1t_{T}}\text{Elevation}(s_{n})\end{array}\right)
+ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}\alpha(1) \\ \alpha(1) \\ \vdots \\ \alpha(1) \\ \vdots \\ \alpha(T) \\ \alpha(T) \\ \vdots \\ \alpha(T)\end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{ccc}\omega(s_{1}) \\ \omega(s_{2}) \\ \vdots \\ \omega(s_{n}) \\ \vdots \\ \omega(s_{1}) \\ \omega(s_{2}) \\ \vdots \\ \omega(s_{n})\end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{ccc}\epsilon \\ \epsilon \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon \\ \epsilon \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon\end{array}\right)\end{equation}

The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from scipy.linalg import inv

# data
url = 'http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~brad/data/ColoradoS-T.dat'
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep='\s+')

elevation = np.array(pd.concat([df[['Elevation']]]*12))
temperature = np.array(df.ix[:, 3:]).reshape(-1)

ntime = 12 # number of months
nsite = 50 # number of measurement sites

# error term epsilon
error_prec = pm.Gamma('error_prec', 0.10, 0.10, value=1.0)
error_prec_m = pm.Lambda('error_prec_m', lambda error_prec=error_prec: np.diag([error_prec]*nsite*ntime))

# intercept and coefficient of covariate in mu.
beta_1 = pm.Normal('beta_1', 0.0, 0.0001, value=[0.0]*ntime, size=ntime)
beta_2 = pm.Normal('beta_2', 0.0, 0.0001, value=[0.0]*ntime, size=ntime)

# precision and variance for covariance matrix associated to time
temporal_prec = pm.Gamma('temporal_prec', 0.10, 0.10, value=1.0)
sigmasq_temp = pm.Lambda('sigmasq_temp', lambda temporal_prec=temporal_prec: 1.0/temporal_prec)
# precision matrix associated to time
phi_t = pm.Uniform('phi_t', 0, 10, value=1.0)
diff_time = squareform(pdist(np.arange(1,13).reshape(12,1), metric='minkowski', p=1))
omega = pm.Lambda('omega', lambda diff_time=diff_time, sigmasq_temp=sigmasq_temp, phi_t=phi_t: 
              inv(sigmasq_temp*np.exp(-phi_t*np.abs(diff_time))))
# calculating value of alpha
V = pm.MvNormal('V', [0]*ntime, omega, value=[0]*ntime)
ones = np.ones((nsite, 1))
# kronecker product of alpha and 1_{nX1} vector
a = pm.Lambda('a', lambda V=V, ones=ones: np.kron(V.reshape(-1,1), ones))

# powered exponential associated to space
diff_space = squareform(pdist(np.array(zip(df['Lon'], df['Lat']))))
spat_prec = pm.Gamma('spat_prec', 0.10, 0.10, value=1.0)
phi = pm.Uniform('phi', 0.0, 10.0, value=1.0)
precision = pm.Lambda('exp', lambda u=diff_space, tau=spat_prec, phi=phi, kappa=1: inv((1/tau)*np.exp(-(phi*u)**kappa)))
# calculating omega from the equation above
w = pm.MvNormal('w', [0]*nsite, precision, value=[0]*nsite)
ones_ = np.ones((ntime, 1))
# kronecker product of 1_{nX1} vector and omega
W = pm.Lambda('W', lambda w=w, ones=ones: np.kron(ones_, w.reshape(-1,1)))

# mean of probability distribution of Y. There is a beta_1 and beta_2 for each time point.
mu = pm.Lambda('mu', lambda beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2, 
               a=a, W=W: (np.kron(beta_1.reshape(-1,1), np.ones((nsite,1))) + 
               np.kron(beta_2.reshape(-1,1), np.ones((nsite,1))) * elevation + a + W).flatten())
# observations
Y = pm.MvNormal('Y', mu, error_prec_m, observed=True, value=temperature)

M = pm.MCMC([Y, mu, error_prec_m, beta_1, beta_2, a, w, phi, phi_t, spat_prec])
M.sample(20000,1000,150)
```

However, after running this, I encounter errors such as:

```
Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda/envs/sc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/database/base.py", line 272, in tally
    self._traces[name].tally(chain)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/envs/sc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/database/ram.py", line 99, in tally
    self._trace[chain][self._index[chain]] = value
IndexError: index 126 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 126

  %s""" % (name, ''.join(traceback.format_exception(cls, inst, tb))))
/home/user/anaconda/envs/sc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/database/base.py:282: UserWarning: 
Error tallying spat_prec, will not try to tally it again this chain.
Did you make all the samevariables and step methods tallyable
as were tallyable last time you used the database file?

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda/envs/sc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/database/base.py", line 272, in tally
    self._traces[name].tally(chain)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/envs/sc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/database/ram.py", line 97, in tally
    self._trace[chain][self._index[chain]] = value.copy()
IndexError: index 126 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 126

  %s""" % (name, ''.join(traceback.format_exception(cls, inst, tb))))
```

The errors vary depending on the number of samples I run and the type of sampling (e.g. pm.AdaptiveMetropolis is faster but produces more errors.) Sometimes, I don't get any errors but the results are not satisfactory. Furthermore, `M.summary()` results in another error:

```
error_prec_m:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-de6c24f0e4aa> in <module>()
----> 1 M.summary()

/home/user/anaconda/envs/sc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/Model.pyc in summary(self, variables, alpha, start, batches, chain, roundto)
    495             variable.summary(
    496                 alpha=alpha, start=start, batches=batches, chain=chain,
--> 497                 roundto=roundto)
    498 
    499     # Property --- status : the sampler state.

/home/user/anaconda/envs/sc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/Node.pyc in summary(self, alpha, start, batches, chain, roundto)
    329         for index in indices:
    330             # Extract statistics and convert to string
--> 331             m = str(round(statdict['mean'][index], roundto))
    332             sd = str(round(statdict['standard deviation'][index], roundto))
    333             mce = str(round(statdict['mc error'][index], roundto))

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

What is the cause of these errors?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to reproduce the first part of your issue, as the model runs just fine. Would it be possible for you to try building from the 2.3 branch?

```
pip install git+git://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc.git@2.3
```

If this fixes it for you, then I will try and get a PyMC 2.3.4 build up on Binstar as soon as I can.

I can repeat the second part of your issue, having to do with the `summary` call, this does appear to be a bug. It is clearly not happy summarizing a 50x50 array. I will fix this.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, I will pip install in a moment and I let you know what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error in branch 2.3.4. Are there other differences between environments? I have numpy 1.9.0, pandas 0.14.1, scipy 0.14.0 and ipython notebook 2.2.0.

Comment: By the way, did you use a large number of samples? I have seen that the error doesn't appear with something like M.sample(2000,500,150).

Comment: Good news is, I fixed the `summary()` bug -- thanks for spotting that. I will push it to the 2.3 branch in a few minutes. As for the other error, I still cannot replicate this even by sampling for thousands of iterations. We have similar setups (PyMC does not use Pandas). Can you double check that your build was installed by checking `pymc.__version__`?

Comment: Great! I checked the version and it is PyMC 2.3.4. I noticed that I start getting errors when I use `M.sample(20000,1000,150)`. If a remember correctly, even `M.sample(15000,1000,150)` doesn't result in errors. By the way, I ran this in a clean anaconda environment. Another unusual thing is that variable `V` outputs an array of zeros only when I pass the parameter `value=[0]*ntime` as above.

Comment: What do you mean by outputting an array of zeros? Do you mean the trace is full of zeros? If so, that means that Metropolis is having trouble, not being able to find its way out of a low-probability space. You can try giving it different initial values (sometimes I even run a MAP estimate on the model to get initial values). Some vector-valued stochastic also may do better under an `AdaptiveMetropolis` sampler.

Comment: I was able to replicate the first bug, so I will figure out what's going on. I think the trace is not being preallocated properly for that particular combination of iterations, burn-in and thinning.

Comment: This should all be fixed now in the 2.3 branch.

Comment: Thank you! Just to let you know, I included more variables  to the sampling function (to be precise `pm.MCMC([Y, mu, error_prec_m, beta_1, beta_2, a, w, phi, phi_t, spat_prec, V])`) and the errors disappeared. Is that related to your solution for the first bug? I also tried AdaptiveMetropolis and I think I get better results, again without errors. Interestingly, plots for the parameter beta are not what I expected, but I will wait to install your fixes.

Comment: I can confirm the first issue has been solved. However, I tried to use `M.sample(100000, 2000, 50)` and I got the second error again, but I haven't been able to reproduce it. I had to use `M.sample(500000,5000,350)` to reproduce the error. In this case, the trace of `error_prec_m` is a (1414, 600, 600) array. Will there always be a limit in the number of iterations allowed by summary()? By the way, the autocorrelations are a bit higher compared to sampling with fewer iterations (both with AdaptiveMetropolis.) Is this normal?

Comment: Its not a limit in the number of iterations, its a problem with improperly pre-allocating the array that stores the samples. I will figure it out.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Should be fixed now!

Comment: Great :-) Is that fix in your latest commit of branch 2.3? https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/commit/81cc0170f171958e4b0421357be0ac32fa2c4323

Comment: I tried it with the latest version of branch 2.3, but now I get a `LinAlgError: singular matrix` error. This is the traceback: http://pastebin.com/4bKc11QD

Comment: Let's move this issue [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/618).

Comment: Sure. Thanks! By the way, in case you're willing to take a look, I asked about another issue using PyMC in Ipython [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306211/kernel-restarting-running-ipython-pymc), although I'm not entirely sure if this is due to Ipython, PyMC or maybe others don't get the same error at all.